# Convert tensorflow to jpeg. Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, jpeg, tfrecord

I'm trying to convert a Tfrecord file to JPEG, but I don't know how to fix this error. I'm new here and in Python, if I did something wrong I'm sorry. If anyone can help me, thank you in advance
error that is giving 
Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=uint8)
Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file
[[node DecodeJpeg (defined at :38) ]]

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
c = 0
totalFile=0
tfrco="/content/drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/ddsm- mammography/training10_0/training10_0.tfrecords"
output_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/ddsm-mammography/training10_0/Images10_0"
for record in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tfrco):
        c += 1

totalFiles=c

tf.reset_default_graph()

fq = tf.train.string_input_producer([tfrco], num_epochs=totalFiles)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, v = reader.read(fq)
fk = {
     'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
     'image/class/synset': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
     'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value='')
    }
ex = tf.parse_single_example(v, fk)
imagem = tf.image.decode_jpeg(ex['image/encoded'], channels=1)
label = tf.cast(ex['image/class/synset'], tf.string)
fileName = tf.cast(ex['image/filename'], tf.string)

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
        tf.local_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess = sess)

num_images=c
print("VAI RESTAURAR {} ARQUIVOS ".format(num_images))
for i in range(num_images):
try:
         im_,lbl,fName = sess.run([imagem,label,fileName])


except Exception as e:
             print(e)
             break
   lbl_=lbl.decode("utf-8")
   savePath=os.path.join(output_path,lbl_)
   if  not os.path.exists(savePath):
       os.makedirs(savePath)
   fName_=os.path.join(savePath, fName.decode("utf-8").split('_')[1])
   cv2.imwrite(fName_ , im_)
   print(fName)
   coord.request_stop()
   coord.join(threads)
```

could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the problem lies in this line: `ex = tf.parse_single_example(v, fk)`, but its hard to tell without further details.

Anyway, I suggest using the `tf.data.Dataset` module to extract and parse the `.tfrecord` files:

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["record.tfrecord", "record1.tfrecord"])
dataset = raw_dataset.map(self._parse_dataset)
```

The `map()` function calls the function it receives as a parameter (in this case `_parse_dataset()`) for every entry in the `tfrecord`. `_parse_datatset()` needs to look something like this:

```
def _parse_dataset(example_proto):
    keys_to_features = {
                 'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
                 'image/class/synset': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
                 'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value='')
            }

    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, keys_to_features)

    return parsed_features['image/encoded'], (parsed_features['image/class/synset'], parsed_features['image/filename'])
```

Now, you can iterate over the elements of `dataset` and convert them back to `JPEG` format:

```
for raw_image, features in dataset:
    imagem = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_image, channels=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Gal, I managed to solve the problem, it really was that, I just had to specify the size of the image. Thanks for the help friend, see you later